# Removing divider after a footer in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, divider

how can I remove the ListView divider after a ListView's footer?
Using `android:footerDividersEnabled="false"` removes the divider after the last item of my ListView, but not after my ListView's footer...

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me, make `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of ListView.

Here is my ListView xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" 
        />
```

Comment: should be accepted, and seems to be epic bug from android

Answer (score -1):

Change the size of your footer to 0px or set the visibility to `GONE`